# php fatal error Uncaught OAuthException: when accessing a php page from facebook application through flash

Tags: php, facebook, flash

I am trying to update a game score from facebook application through flash.

```
function postdatas(){ 

var postpath="post.php";       
var my_vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
my_vars.times = encrypt(game.stopwatch.minText.text+"."+game.stopwatch.secText.text, "PheNi3$@$%!");

var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(postpath);
my_url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
my_url.data = my_vars;

var my_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
my_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
my_loader.load(my_url);
}

postdatas();
```

In Post.php

I am getting facebook user info to update a message in his wall and updating score in database

```
$fbme  =   $facebook->api('/me');
```

But i am getting "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out, Need to pass the signedrequest to the post.php